# How to get name of streams in MinibatchSource?

Tags: cntk

How can I get the names of each of the streams in a MinibatchSource?

Can I get the names associated with with the stream information returned by stream_infos?

minibatch_source.stream_infos()

I also have a follow-up-question:

The result from:
print(reader_train.streams.keys())
is
dict_keys(['labels', 'features'

How does these names relate to the construction of the MiniBatchSource, which is done like this?

```
return MinibatchSource(ImageDeserializer(map_file, StreamDefs(
    features = StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms), # first column in map file is referred to as 'image'
    labels   = StreamDef(field='label', shape=num_classes)      # and second as 'label'
)))
```

I would have thought that my streams would be named ‘image’ and ‘label’, but they were named ‘labels’ and ‘features’.

I guess those names are somehow default names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question:

```
minibatch_source.streams.keys()
```

See for example [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.beta7.0/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb) under the section "A Brief Look at Data and Data Reading".

For your followup question: The names returned by `keys()` are the arguments of `StreamDefs()`. This is all you need in your program. If you define your `MinibatchSource` like this

```
return MinibatchSource(ImageDeserializer(map_file, StreamDefs(
image = StreamDef(field='image', transforms=transforms), # first column in map file is referred to as 'image'
label = StreamDef(field='label', shape=num_classes)      # and second as 'label')))
```

then the names will match. You can choose any names you want but the value of the `field` inside `StreamDef()` should match the source (which depends on your input data and the Deserializer you are using).